# "Remove" alternatives of union type of anonymus objects

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have union types with a **know** discriminator field, in this case `disc`. These union types are unions of object literals, and other than the discriminator field they can have arbitrary fields, for example:

```js
type Union =
  | { disc: "a"; someField: string }
  | { disc: "b"; some: boolean; field: number }
  | { disc: "c"; foo: number }
  | { disc: "d" };
```

How could I make a generic type, that "removes" some union alternatives, based on the `disc` (discriminator) field? Is this possible with TypeScript?

Eg.:

```js
type SomeTypeTransform<Type, Keys> = ???

type UnionWithoutCAndD = SomeTypeTransform<Union, "c" | "d">

type CAndDManuallyRemoved =
  | { disc: "a"; someField: string }
  | { disc: "b"; some: boolean; field: number }

// I'd like UnionWithoutCAndD to be equivalent with CAndDManuallyRemoved
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually already built-in (as `Exclude`), but you need a *little* more magic:

```
type SomeTypeTransform<Type, Keys> = Exclude<Type, { disc: Keys }>;
```

From the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers):

> `Exclude<UnionType, ExcludedMembers>`
>
> Constructs a type by excluding from `UnionType` all union members that are **assignable to** `ExcludedMembers`.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NdreQW)

Comment: That's incredibly simple thank you!